# How do I stop the D key from showing desktop

Tags: rdp

I have setup my ubuntu box so I can use Windows remote desktop to log into it.  I was trying to use the terminal and when I tried to type the cd command, it typed the c but the d key minimized the screen.  Pressing d again brought the window back.  Open more windows, same effect.

It appears that d is triggering the show desktop command.  None of my alt, ctrl, or shift keys are pressed.  When I do press alt key, it brings up the menu like I expect.  When I press shift or caps, I can actually type a capital D.  when capslock is on, and I press shift and d, it does the show desktop again.

One other note, my password has a lowercase d, so it types correctly until I get into the desktop.  I'm using the Ubuntu classic desktop.

I'm new to ubuntu and linux, and I'm not the most familiar with the configuration settings.  What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have CompizConfig setting manager installed open the application and choose General, General option, key bindings and look what keybinding is assigned to "Show Desktop" and change it as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I have put the following into `/etc/profile` to get around this problem with pressing the "d" key

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/show_desktop -t String "disabled"
```